# List all Excel Add-ins in a client machine

Tags: .net, excel, registry, excel-addins, office-addins

**Problem:**

I want to list all Excel add-ins (**not COM add-ins**) of every Excel version installed on a machine.
Could you please give my any clue or suggestion?

**What I have done**

I've tried getting the information from registry keys. For Office 2013, it is here.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Components\72EFF0976DEDB96428D4154EFA5A5807

But for Office 2007, it is not there.

The data for the key are :

1. analys32.xll

   - Data = Analysis ToolPak\Provides data analysis tools for statistical and engineering analysis
2. atpvbaen.xlam

   - Data = Analysis ToolPak - VBA\VBA functions for Analysis ToolPak
3. eurotool.xlam

   - Data = Euro Currency Tools\Conversion and formatting for the euro currency
4. solver.xlam

   - Data = Solver Add-in\Tool for optimization and equation solving

Is there a way to achive this without hard-coding Components GUID for every Excel version?

Comment: I think those are only the add-ins that are installed by default. My addins are listed under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Add-in Manager`

Comment: @Dick Wow, I missed that point. Thank you so much.